# is there a way to randomly run a function from a set of checked checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I was trying to make it so that when I press a button it will run a random function, but will only run ones that have a checked checkbox.

here is what I have Tried:

```
//all functions
var functs = [
  function1,
  function2,
  function3
]

//functioned called when button is pressed
function runRandomFunct() {

  //checks if a checkbox is checked
  var c1 = document.getElementById('check1');
  var c2 = document.getElementById('check2');
  var c3 = document.getElementById('check3');
  var theCs = [
    c1.checked,
    c2.checked,
    c3.checked,
  ]

  //creates a new array for only the functions that had a checked box
  var checkedFuncts = []

  var y = 0;

  //puts the functions in the new array
  for (z = 0, z < theCs[].length, z++) {
    if (theCs[z] === true) {
      checkedFuncts[y] = functs[z];
      y = y++;
    }
  }

  let numOfCheckedFuncts = checkedFuncts[].length;
  let chosenFunct = Math.floor(Math.random() * numOfCheckedFuncts);
  checkedFuncts[chosenFunct]();
}
```

can anyone tell me how this can be done?

Comment: `y = y++;` should be just `y++`. Or don't use `y` at all, just use `checkedFuncts.push(functs[z])`

Comment: `checkedFuncts[].length` should be `checkedFuncts.length`. That should have caused a syntax error.

Comment: Other than these typos, your basic approach is fine.

Comment: you can also use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get list of elements with a class instead of having to hardcode all ids.